# NameError: name 'Task' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-2.7

please someone help me to solve this problem

```
# **Admin.py**
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Task

admin.site.register(Task)

# **view.py**
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from .models import Task

class TaskList(ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'tasks'
{Error
 from .models import Task
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package}


# **Model.py**
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User



# Create your models here.
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['complete']
```

**
when is run on server the specific result on come and but server works perfectly.
when i run the code its send this error